# Why we have 3 places to manage external sharing for out MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, external-users, modern-team-site, guest-access

Inside our Office 365 we have 3 places to manage the external sharing for MS Teams, as follow:-

1. Inside the modern team sharepoint site that got created

[image]

2. Inside the Team's Org-wide setting >> External Access + inside the Team's Org-wide setting >> Guest Access, as follow:-

[image]

so how those 3 places work together? for example we are only allowing the sharepoint site to be shared with people in our organization, while we have enabled the Guest Access + External Access inside the Org-wide settings... so will external users be able to use the MS Teams or not?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are 4 places, not 3 to manage `external collaboration` and `guest access` in Teams.

- Azure Active Directory Settings.
- Guest Access Settings in Microsoft Teams.
- Guest Settings in Microsoft 365 Groups.
- SharePoint Sharing Settings for organization and sites

So to avoid such confusion, you have first to understand [Guest access Vs External access in Teams](https://debug.to/948/guest-access-vs-external-access-in-teams) then configure the above 4 steps as mentioned at [Unable to add a guest to Microsoft Teams](https://debug.to/947/unable-to-add-guest-to-microsoft-teams)

> **Note:** Guest Access in MS Teams Admin Center may take up to 24 hours for the Teams guest settings to become active after you turn it on.

Comment: so in our case we have external and guest access enalbed while we have disable external sharing inside the modern team sharepoint site.. so what will be the case? will it be that we can chat with external users using MS Teams while they can not access the files we share with them, since they can not access the sharepoint site?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior because you are disabling the sharing on **SharePoint** org and site level

Comment: but our Org-wide setting enables external and guest access

Comment: Yes, this for Teams settings as one of the required steps to enable guest access and external collaboration, but I don't talk about team org that you have already enabled, I talk about sharepoint org and site-level and you have said you disabled the sharepoint sharing setting right?

Comment: yes .. the external sharing inside sharepoint site is disabled

Comment: So they can meet with external users using MS Teams but they can not access the files you share with them, because they don't access the SharePoint site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118205/discussion-between-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-and-john-john).